# How to set persistence in Firebase Storage on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'am using Firebase Storage to get a list of images on Android, but every time when the App is started this list is downloaded, I want store persistence on Android the images and download only if is necessary. So I need to check if the images that will downloaded already are on the smartphone. I'am using the FirebaseDatabase to store the name of the files, for the Database I can check the persistence. I think need store images on the storage of device, but I don't know to check before download, so the best way is set persistence FirebaseStorage if possible.

My code looks like this:

FirebaseDatabase:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference().child("nomes_imagens");

        final Map<String,Object> mapNomesImagens = new HashMap<>();

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG,"onDataChanged()");
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = iterator.next();
                    mapNomesImagens.put(snapshot.getKey(),snapshot.getValue());
                    n1++;
                }

                makeList(mapNomesImagens);
                Log.i(TAG,"Mapa: " + mapNomesImagens.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i(TAG,"onCancelled");
            }
        });
```

FirebaseStorage:

```
public boolean makeList(Map<String,Object> map) {
    final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    try {
        Set<String> set = map.keySet();

        for(final String nomeExercicio : set) {

            String nomeArquivo = String.valueOf(map.get(nomeExercicio));

            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("ImagensExercicios","bmp");
            storage.getReference().child("ImagensExercicios").child(nomeArquivo).getFile(localFile).
                    addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"onSuccess()");
                            Bitmap bitmap;
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            Exercicio exercicio = new Exercicio(nomeExercicio,bitmap);
                            exercicios.add(exercicio);
                            n++;
                        }
                    }).
                    addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"onFailure() " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }).
                    addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            Log.i(TAG,"onComplete()");
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK setpersistence enabling is intended for offline data storage. So it will refresh when the internet is available.

You can use Glide library to handle caching. Official firebase usage with Glide given below must be sufficient.

Link: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage

> To load an image from a StorageReference, simply use the
>   FirebaseImageLoader class:
>
> ```
> // Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
> StorageReference storageReference = ...;
>
> // ImageView in your Activity
> ImageView imageView = ...;
>
> // Load the image using Glide
> Glide.with(this /* context */)
>         .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
>         .load(storageReference)
>         .into(imageView);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Send the picture path or URI in the phone, create a room android database, or if you are good with persistence that's ok. Use regular expression or regex to help tally the URI path from firebase to that of the phone path.

If both URI match then the file exists no need to download but if the URI does not match then the file does not exist then a download process is trigger

Remember regular expression or regex